# RStudio knitr themes

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

I've just started playing with some of the new knitr features in RStudio.

I've tried selecting several of the different themes in the R Markdown settings dialogue but these don't seem to have any noticeable impact on the style of my resulting document. Should it, or am I missing something? Everything just seems to come out in the default style no matter what theme I select.

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    number_sections: yes
    theme: spacelab
    toc: yes
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
---
```

[image: R Markdown Options]
[image: Result of export]

Installation details:

- R version 3.1.1
- RStudio Version 0.98.977
- knitr 1.6
- rmarkdown 0.2.50
- htmltools 0.2.4
- Windows 7

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Learning the following led me to the solution.

Two different things show up if you google "knitr theme".

1. `highlight` parameter = syntax highlighting ([1](http://rclickhandbuch.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/knitrthemesoverview.pdf), [2](http://animation.r-forge.r-project.org/knitr/), [3](https://gist.github.com/yihui/3422133)—familiar keywords like kate, tango, solarized-dark)
2. `theme` parameter = bootswatch CSS (these are the less familiar keywords like [spacelab](http://bootswatch.com/spacelab), superhero, united, yeti)

[Here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#appearance-and-style) are the instructions of how to add the correct knitr flags at the top of your `.Rmd` file.

---

Once you've added something like

```
---
title: "Impressive Client Report"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: spacelab
    highlight: neon
---
```

to the top, then open `R` in the directory where your `.Rmd` file lives, and run

```
require(knitr)
knit(input='impressive report.Rmd', output='impressive_report.Rhtml')
```

*(I switched  to `_` because of another gotcha: I was switching between command-line `R` and RStudio knitting, not realising that RStudio was creating a different `.html` file to the one `R` was creating.)*

---

Or in the case of RStudio, just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to `knit` your `.Rmd` file from the editing window—*after* changing both `theme` and `highlight` to valid values.

Comment: What if i want to use "autumn" theme as it's indicated in the link [1](http://rclickhandbuch.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/knitrthemesoverview.pdf) you provided above. I don't see it as one of the options. In fact when i try your solution, i get an error:

`Error in match.arg(highlight, html_highlighters()) : 
  'arg' should be one of “default”, “tango”, “pygments”, “kate”, “monochrome”, “espresso”, “zenburn”, “haddock”, “textmate”`

Any idea how i can use the "autumn" theme?

Comment: @Lalas That person seems to be using `Tinn R` … and it [looks like](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#appearance-and-style) RStudio doesn't support the `autumn` highlight style.

I haven't used TinnR but [he](https://rclickhandbuch.wordpress.com/install-r/tinn-r_english/) has written some instructions on getting it going.

Comment: @Lalas Hunting this down a bit more: since everything is passed through `pandoc` (and those `match.arg...html_highlighters...` options seem to come from what `pandoc` allows) — you might be able to steal highlighting files, [which should look like this](https://github.com/jgm/highlighting-kate/blob/master/css/hk-pyg.css) I guess, from TinnR's source code and then change the `pandoc` call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081354/custom-syntax-highlighting-rmd) which indicates that it wasn't possible, at least with Rmd file, which is what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same problem and I was able to solve it by placing the theme argument before any other arguments. I am unsure if the order matters, but in my case it did. For example, this correctly changes my html theme:

```
---
title: "A Title"
author: "An Author"
date: "last update: `r format(Sys.Date(), format = '%d %B %Y')`" 
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: flatly
    highlight: haddock
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
      smooth_scroll: true
---
```

While providing the theme argument towards the end did not work:

```
---
title: "A Title"
author: "An Author"
date: "last update: `r format(Sys.Date(), format = '%d %B %Y')`" 
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
      smooth_scroll: true
  theme: flatly
  highlight: haddock
---
```

This also was true for my syntax highlighting argument.

Comment: What happens if you indent `theme` and `highlight` one more level in your second example?  In the first example the "parent" is `html_document` but in the second it's `output`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct @dnlbrky. When I changed the order, I also changed the indentation. The solution I posted here is not entirely accurate (in terms of the ordering of statements). The indentation level is what provides the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you activate the following option in your RStudio:
Tools --> Global Options... --> Sweave --> Weave Rnw files using: knitr

At least it worked with me while compiling pdf from tex format.