# Change the background colour of code ouput in Rmd script when exporting to PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

How do I change the background of the output of my code? So here's an example a basic rmarkdown document:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---
## Simple calculation

```{r}
1 + 1
```

## A for loop

```{r}
for (i in 1:20) {
  # nothing before 10
  if (i >= 10)
    print(i)
}
```
````

which compiles to give:

[image]

How do I set things up so that the code prefixed with "##" also has a shading?

Thanks,
Stuples

EDIT: I'm after the combined look of code input and output as shown in the [knitr-themes.pdf](https://bitbucket.org/stat/knitr/downloads/knitr-themes.pdf)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934781/rstudio-knitr-themes

Comment: knitr themes are for .Rnw/.Rhtml files only; they do not apply to R Markdown. For R Markdown, if you want to customize anything, you have to spend a fair amount of time on learning LaTeX and Pandoc, which is not worth it in my opinion if the background color is the only thing that bothers you.

Comment: Thanks Yihui. Over the last couple of days, I've ended up learning knitr with the aim of then using LaTeX rather than R Markdown.

Comment: For what it's worth, I found out that `\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{255,100,50}` lets you redefine the background color of your code blocks itself (the original color is `248,248,248`). For code output I set `keep_tex: yes` in the yaml header. The code output in the tex file is inside `verbatim` environments, so I defined a new environment (such as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53951/163196)) and changed all verbatims to the new environment